# pre-process and load the NSL_KDD data set

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

since I am a newbie in python programming and I want to load the data according to the table of the article but I don’t know how to can do categorical training and testing the NSL_KDD dataset into(‘normal’, ‘dos’, ‘r2l’, ‘probe’, ‘u2r’).
[image]

I’ve reviewed a lot of code in GateHub to pre-process the NSL_KDD data set to categorize into five groups(‘normal’, ‘dos’, ‘r2l’, ‘probe’, ‘u2r’), but I still haven’t been able to find the code to do it right.
Can anyone help me? I really need help.

Answer (score 0):

This code for loading you can find how to [PCA algorithm is used for visualization purposes. It's also used later as preprocessing for Gaussian Mixture clustering.](https://render.githubusercontent.com/view/ipynb?commit=03bab6212c3058d6c87f8b740550231d8d5d64e3&enc_url=68747470733a2f2f7261772e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f7468696e6c696e6537322f6e736c2d6b64642f303362616236323132633330353864366338376638623734303535303233316438643564363465332f4e534c2d4b44442e6970796e62&nwo=thinline72%2Fnsl-kdd&path=NSL-KDD.ipynb&repository_id=70263928&repository_type=Repository#9.-Gaussian-Mixture-clustering-with-Random-Forest-Classifier)

```
import os
import math
import itertools
import multiprocessing
import pandas
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from time import time
from collections import OrderedDict
%matplotlib inline
gt0 = time()

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row

conf = SparkConf()\
    .setMaster(f"local[{multiprocessing.cpu_count()}]")\
    .setAppName("PySpark NSL-KDD")\
    .setAll([("spark.driver.memory", "8g"), ("spark.default.parallelism", f"{multiprocessing.cpu_count()}")])

# Creating local SparkContext with specified SparkConf and creating SQLContext based on it
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
sc.setLogLevel('INFO')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, split, col
import pyspark.sql.functions as sql

train20_nsl_kdd_dataset_path = os.path.join("NSL_KDD_Dataset", "KDDTrain+_20Percent.txt")
train_nsl_kdd_dataset_path = os.path.join("NSL_KDD_Dataset", "KDDTrain+.txt")
test_nsl_kdd_dataset_path = os.path.join("NSL_KDD_Dataset", "KDDTest+.txt")

col_names = np.array(["duration","protocol_type","service","flag","src_bytes",
"dst_bytes","land","wrong_fragment","urgent","hot","num_failed_logins",
"logged_in","num_compromised","root_shell","su_attempted","num_root",
"num_file_creations","num_shells","num_access_files","num_outbound_cmds",
"is_host_login","is_guest_login","count","srv_count","serror_rate",
"srv_serror_rate","rerror_rate","srv_rerror_rate","same_srv_rate",
"diff_srv_rate","srv_diff_host_rate","dst_host_count","dst_host_srv_count",
"dst_host_same_srv_rate","dst_host_diff_srv_rate","dst_host_same_src_port_rate",
"dst_host_srv_diff_host_rate","dst_host_serror_rate","dst_host_srv_serror_rate",
"dst_host_rerror_rate","dst_host_srv_rerror_rate","labels"])

nominal_inx = [1, 2, 3]
binary_inx = [6, 11, 13, 14, 20, 21]
numeric_inx = list(set(range(41)).difference(nominal_inx).difference(binary_inx))
nominal_inx = [1, 2, 3]
binary_inx = [6, 11, 13, 14, 20, 21]
numeric_inx = list(set(range(41)).difference(nominal_inx).difference(binary_inx))

nominal_cols = col_names[nominal_inx].tolist()
binary_cols = col_names[binary_inx].tolist()
numeric_cols = col_names[numeric_inx].tolist()


# Function to load dataset and divide it into 8 partitions
def load_dataset(path):
    dataset_rdd = sc.textFile(path, 8).map(lambda line: line.split(','))
    dataset_df = (dataset_rdd.toDF(col_names.tolist()).select(
                    col('duration').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('protocol_type').cast(StringType()),
                    col('service').cast(StringType()),
                    col('flag').cast(StringType()),
                    col('src_bytes').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('dst_bytes').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('land').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('wrong_fragment').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('urgent').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('hot').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('num_failed_logins').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('logged_in').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('num_compromised').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('root_shell').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('su_attempted').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('num_root').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('num_file_creations').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('num_shells').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('num_access_files').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('num_outbound_cmds').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('is_host_login').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('is_guest_login').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('count').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('srv_count').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('serror_rate').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('srv_serror_rate').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('rerror_rate').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('srv_rerror_rate').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('same_srv_rate').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('diff_srv_rate').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('srv_diff_host_rate').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('dst_host_count').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('dst_host_srv_count').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('dst_host_same_srv_rate').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('dst_host_diff_srv_rate').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('dst_host_same_src_port_rate').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('dst_host_srv_diff_host_rate').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('dst_host_serror_rate').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('dst_host_srv_serror_rate').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('dst_host_rerror_rate').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('dst_host_srv_rerror_rate').cast(DoubleType()),
                    col('labels').cast(StringType())))

    return dataset_df

from pyspark.ml import Pipeline, Transformer
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark import keyword_only
from pyspark.ml.param.shared import HasInputCol, HasOutputCol, Param

# Dictionary that contains mapping of various attacks to the four main categories
attack_dict = {
    'normal': 'normal',

    'back': 'DoS',
    'land': 'DoS',
    'neptune': 'DoS',
    'pod': 'DoS',
    'smurf': 'DoS',
    'teardrop': 'DoS',
    'mailbomb': 'DoS',
    'apache2': 'DoS',
    'processtable': 'DoS',
    'udpstorm': 'DoS',

    'ipsweep': 'Probe',
    'nmap': 'Probe',
    'portsweep': 'Probe',
    'satan': 'Probe',
    'mscan': 'Probe',
    'saint': 'Probe',

    'ftp_write': 'R2L',
    'guess_passwd': 'R2L',
    'imap': 'R2L',
    'multihop': 'R2L',
    'phf': 'R2L',
    'spy': 'R2L',
    'warezclient': 'R2L',
    'warezmaster': 'R2L',
    'sendmail': 'R2L',
    'named': 'R2L',
    'snmpgetattack': 'R2L',
    'snmpguess': 'R2L',
    'xlock': 'R2L',
    'xsnoop': 'R2L',
    'worm': 'R2L',

    'buffer_overflow': 'U2R',
    'loadmodule': 'U2R',
    'perl': 'U2R',
    'rootkit': 'U2R',
    'httptunnel': 'U2R',
    'ps': 'U2R',    
    'sqlattack': 'U2R',
    'xterm': 'U2R'
}

attack_mapping_udf = udf(lambda v: attack_dict[v])

class Labels2Converter(Transformer):

    @keyword_only
    def __init__(self):
        super(Labels2Converter, self).__init__()

    def _transform(self, dataset):
        return dataset.withColumn('labels2', sql.regexp_replace(col('labels'), '^(?!normal).*$', 'attack'))

class Labels5Converter(Transformer):

    @keyword_only
    def __init__(self):
        super(Labels5Converter, self).__init__()

    def _transform(self, dataset):
        return dataset.withColumn('labels5', attack_mapping_udf(col('labels')))

labels2_indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="labels2", outputCol="labels2_index")
labels5_indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="labels5", outputCol="labels5_index")

labels_mapping_pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[Labels2Converter(), Labels5Converter(), labels2_indexer, labels5_indexer])

labels2 = ['normal', 'attack']
labels5 = ['normal', 'DoS', 'Probe', 'R2L', 'U2R']
labels_col = 'labels2_index'

# Loading train data
t0 = time()
train_df = load_dataset(train_nsl_kdd_dataset_path)

# Fitting preparation pipeline
labels_mapping_model = labels_mapping_pipeline.fit(train_df)

# Transforming labels column and adding id column
train_df = labels_mapping_model.transform(train_df).withColumn('id', sql.monotonically_increasing_id())

train_df = train_df.cache()
print(f"Number of examples in train set: {train_df.count()}")
print(f"Time: {time() - t0:.2f}s")

# Loading test data
t0 = time()
test_df = load_dataset(test_nsl_kdd_dataset_path)

# Transforming labels column and adding id column
test_df = labels_mapping_model.transform(test_df).withColumn('id', sql.monotonically_increasing_id())

test_df = test_df.cache()
print(f"Number of examples in test set: {test_df.count()}")
print(f"Time: {time() - t0:.2f}s")
```

Comment: when I ran these code received this error. 
  File "G:/RUN_PYTHON/load.py", line 55, in <module>
    binary_cols = col_names[binary_inx].tolist()

IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5                                               
what that's the problem? could you please help me?
regards

Comment: binary_inx has 6 elements while col_names has 5. Please correct as I did in my answer.

Comment: I don't know how to can correct it, could you please edit for me?

Comment: I edited my answer and please look at this link to adjust what you want: https://render.githubusercontent.com/view/ipynb?commit=03bab6212c3058d6c87f8b740550231d8d5d64e3&enc_url=68747470733a2f2f7261772e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f7468696e6c696e6537322f6e736c2d6b64642f303362616236323132633330353864366338376638623734303535303233316438643564363465332f4e534c2d4b44442e6970796e62&nwo=thinline72%2Fnsl-kdd&path=NSL-KDD.ipynb&repository_id=70263928&repository_type=Repository#9.-Gaussian-Mixture-clustering-with-Random-Forest-Classifier

Comment: @ Mahsa Hassankashi, thanks for your response. I referred this link for load and pre-process the data but in some sections of code, I don't know what the problem is that I received these errors. On the other hand, when I run the edited code above, I get this message:Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o68.partitions.
: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/NSL_KDD_Dataset/KDDTrain+.txt
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:287)

Comment: It is because of your 4th section. This line: train_nsl_kdd_dataset_path = os.path.join("NSL_KDD_Dataset", "KDDTrain+.txt"). Did you locate it correctly?

Comment: ,is it right that download the data and past the path into section 4 according to the follows:train20_nsl_kdd_dataset_path = os.path.join("G:/RUN_PYTHON/New folder", "KDDTrain+_20Percent.txt")
train_nsl_kdd_dataset_path = os.path.join("G:/RUN_PYTHON/New folder", "KDDTrain+.txt")
test_nsl_kdd_dataset_path = os.path.join("G:/RUN_PYTHON/New folder", "KDDTest+.txt")

Comment: After the paste dataset, what was your exception?

Comment: ,I did it but get this message:@Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
 at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:420)
 at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.write(NioSocketImpl.java:440)

Comment: Your Resilient Distributed Datasets (RDD) is getting empty in 5th section line: dataset_rdd = sc.textFile(path, 8).map(lambda line: line.split(',')). The null pointer exception indicates that an aggregation task is attempted against a null value. Check your data for null in 3th section: sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf), you should create local SparkContext with specified SparkConf and creating SQLContext based on it.

Comment: @ Mahsa Hassankashi, I am a newbie in python and spark and I don't know how to can do it.could you please help me? thanks to your response, regards

Comment: Are you familiar with Google Colab? Try to run it https://colab.research.google.com/

Comment: Install spark on ubuntu:https://www.programcreek.com/2018/11/install-spark-on-ubuntu-standalone-mode/  Spark Configuration 
 https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/configuration.html#spark-configuration